# Firestore prevent malicious user to add more data than wanted

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I'm using Angular for my frontend and Cloud functions + Firestore for my backend.

When I `set` data in Firestore, I want to limit the users to a certain model of data. For example let's say that my "model" is:

```js
    interface Person {
        name: string
        age: number
    }
```

Nothing prevents a malicious user to send an object like the following:

```js
    {
       name: 'Anna', 
       age: 22,
       unWantedData: 'Some unwanted data' 
    }
```

What is the best way to prevent that ?
I've seen the [Firestore converters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) but is it really the way to go ?

I also have another related question. I'm quite familiar working with SQL and ORM's using Entities, for example with `TypeORM`:

```js
    @Entity()
    export class Post {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
        id: number
    
        @Column()
        @Length(10, 20)
        title: string
    
        @Column()
        @IsInt()
        @Min(0)
        @Max(10)
        rating: number
    
        @Column()
        @IsEmail()
        email: string
    
        @Column()
        @IsDate()
        createDate: Date
    }
```

Is there a way to have **validators** like that with Firestore ? Maybe using rules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer in the last line of your question: you can indeed use Firebase's server-side security rules to [validate the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation).

The security rules only apply to access from the client-side SDKs, not from connections over the Admin SDK (such as those from Cloud Functions that you mention). If writes happen through such a trusted environment, you will have to validate the data in your application code before passing it to Firebase.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, I need to map the data and create the validators by myself in my cloud function code ?

Comment: If you perform the writes in Cloud Functions yes you will have to validate the data in that code. If you perform them in the client-side application code, you can use security rules.

Comment: Ok thank you. And there are no tools out there that can help with "schema valitation" and field validators ?

Comment: There may be, but that's a question that's better suited for a search engine (recommendations for libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow). Whatever you end up using, it'll have to be in your Cloud Functions code if that is where you write to Firestore from.